CSS para alterar texto
Estou tentando alterar o texto do botão Finalizar Compra em uma loja, porém não está funcionando... Poderiam verificar meu CSS?
button.ui-button.-lg.-primary.-block.btn-checkout::after {
    content: "Avançar na Compra";
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    color: inherit !important; /* Mantém a cor original do texto */
    background: transparent !important; /* Fundo transparente */
    pointer-events: none !important; /* Permite cliques no botão */
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

button.ui-button.-lg.-primary.-block.btn-checkout {
    position: relative !important;
    color: transparent !important; /* Esconde o texto original */
}

Obrigada!

Importante você [edit] sua pergunta convertendo o código em um [mcve] do problema, explicar como tentou resolver e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.
